# video.js mp4 iphone native player override

Tags: iphone, html, mp4

Using video.js:

I only have a video format mp4. I have captions for it set up and working on desktop and android (galaxy s3). The iPhone automatically plays the video in the native player which makes the captions not work.

Is there a way around this?

Comment: Still an issue today. I found that the native player WILL read SRT or VTT captions but it has to be set up to do so, in the iPhone settings. More here: http://video.stackexchange.com/questions/12985/why-do-srt-subtitles-fail-to-appear-in-my-mp4-videos-on-iphones